# Waiting on QMutex asserts

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have discovered that even a simple wait on QMutex will cause assertion. What am I possibly doing wrong?

```
QMutex mutex;

SyncMgr::SyncMgr(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    moveToThread( &thread  );

    thread.start();

    process = new QProcess( this);

    connect( process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(onReadyReadStandardOutput() ) );
    connect( process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(onReadyReadStandardError() ) );
}

SyncMgr::~SyncMgr()
{
    delete process;
}

void SyncMgr::onConnected()
{
    cmdDispatcher.sendGetSerialNo();

    // this asserts
    waitForResponse.wait( &mutex ); // waitForResponse is CWaitCondition object

    // ...
}
```

I get assert and the error message is:

> ASSERT:'copy' in the thread\qmutex.cpp, line 525

Comment: This may have to do with 'recursion mode' for QMutest. Do you set RecursionMode to Recursive while creating the mutex?

Comment: mutex should be a class member, and you need to lock it (use  QMutexLocker) before calling wait(). Not sure if that is related to the assertion though.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I tried both and nothing changed.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld It shouldn't matter if its class member or global but still I tried and no effect but even if it is unlocked why should it assert?

Comment: Reading the code that leads to the assertion (qmutex.cpp:525):     QMutexData *copy = `d_ptr.loadAcquire(); Q_ASSERT(copy); //we must be locked`. That suggests not being locked is exactly what triggers it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to lock the mutex before calling waitForResponse.wait().
The SyncMgr::onConnected() method should look like this:

```
void SyncMgr::onConnected()
{
    cmdDispatcher.sendGetSerialNo();

    mutex.lock();
    waitForResponse.wait( &mutex );
    // do something
    mutex.unlock();

    ...
}
```

You can find more information here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html#wait